# How to process window message with bufferization

Tags: winapi, hook, barcode-scanner

I have a WH_GETMESSAGE hook that catches WM_KEYDOWN and WM_INPUT (right now only WM_KEYDOWN), what i need is a way to measure time intervals between WM_KEYDOWNs to see how fast user typing. Exactly i need to drop entire keystroke if it was inputed too fast (i.e. input wasn't actually from user, but from some HID keyboard device, like barcode scanner). What i need to do is for each symbol i'm gonna wait for 30 ms and then if none further symbols applied i need to send it to window it was meant for. And that check need to be performed on each WM_KEYDOWN.  If new symbol applied i will push it to my queue along with any further symbols that will go within 30 ms limit between messages (actually i tested on my computer it takes something like 31-32 ms to input symbol and barcode scanner needs something like 15-16 ms which will be sufficent).

I figured out following algorithm: 
1. If incoming message is WM_KEYDOWN - store it (with time offcourse). 
2. If next incoming message isn't WM_KEYDOWN or time-limit exceeded - send stored message to it's recipient and store current message if it's WM_KEYDOWN - go to step 1. 
3. If next message came in 30 ms limit - store it too.
4. If next message is VK_RETURN or sequence is longer than 128 symbols - drop current sequence and store it as barcode. Goto step 1.

Current flaw in this algorithm is that sendMessage thing. I used both sendMessage and postMessage but they both just resend it to my hook procedure (which is obvious i guess). Is there any way to just send this message directly to window it was mento to be send?

Or maybe there are other solution for my problem?

My explanation may seem ambiguous so i just write what i need to achieve: 
I need to intercept barcode scanner input before it actually reaches window procedure, so no WM_KEYDOWN messages from scanner will reach target window. A barcode message are typically comes with 15-16ms interval between single WM_KEYDOWNs and ends with VK_RETURN.

Also i need to use exactly WH_GETMESSAGE (or similiar hook that will allow me to catch both WM_INPUT and WM_KEYDOWN). WM_INPUT is needed to distinguish input from various devices (basically i'm going to enum all HID keyboards, determine which of them send barcodes if such event occurs i will flag device as barcode scanner and store it's VID&PID to local database and it will be use for other).

Comment: `GetMessage` is too late. The shift states will be out of sync if you try to replay the input there. You may have better luck with a low-level keyboard hook and using SendInput for replay. (You can use the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag to avoid the recursion problem.)

Comment: I don't have that oportunity, thing is WH_KEYBOARD_LL works on lower level than RawInput, so it's messages sent earlier than WM_INPUT and i can't compare two and thus can't discard unwanted keyboard input. At the moment i'm going to just call WndProc myself and wait before it will process message, i hope it won't try to call DefWindowProc upon completion.